# SQL Script to populate a new field with auto number based on groups of other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, auto-increment

I need to populate a column (C3) with autoincrement IDs based on the values of two other columns (Unique ID for Unique C1-C2 values)

**Current**

```
  C1        C2      C3
------------------------------
    X       A       null
    X       A       null
    Y       A       null
    Z       B       null
    Z       B       null
    Z       B       null
```

**Desired**

```
  C1        C2      C3
------------------------------
    X       A       1
    X       A       1
    Y       A       2
    Z       B       3
    Z       B       3
    Z       B       3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is described by:

```
select c1, c2, dense_rank() over (order by c1)
from t;
```

You might intend:

```
select c1, c2, dense_rank() over (order by c1, c2)
from t;
```

(But this is more complicated than needed for your sample data.)

This depends on the ordering of the values columns themselves.  I am guessing that you have some sort of id and you want the rows ordered by that id.  The same idea still holds, but you use the minimum id:

```
select c1, c2,
       dense_rank() over (order by minid)
from (select t.*, min(id) over (partition by c1, c2) as minid
      from t
     ) t;
```